# Is there a "Group Transparency/Opacity" option in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, symbology, transparency-opacity

When displaying multiple overlapping vector or raster layers, is there a way to have QGIS render them as a group *before* applying transparency?

I can see this question has been asked a few times on here and that a QGIS feature request was raised over a decade ago (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/1898), but I'm unable to find a solution.

Edit: I can see that there is a more up to date feature proposal here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/235

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible since QGIS version 3.24, when the Feature: [Rendering layers as groups](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-rendering-layers-as-groups) was added.

Click on the group in layer panel, go to Layer styling and check the box `Render Layers as a Group`. Then set the transparency of the group.

*The pink building polygons are only shown transparent where there are no orange polygons from the same group covering because the group is first drawn and orange cover pink polygons. Then this group is set to transaprent:*
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you can see this feature on 3.26.xx latest release, but it doesn't seem to available yet for the LTR. Great feature!

Comment: Thanks @Snowy for mentioning that. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I've noticed this option doesn't seem to work if I save, close, and reopen a workspace. The opacity slider no longer works and if I select another layer/group and come back to this group, the "render layer as a group" box is unticked again. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should Post this as a separate question